# How to URLencode a URL in ampscript?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, url-encode

I am trying to set URL in my ampscript, but it changes the "?" in the url into "&". I tried to wrap the url between URLEncode("www.sample.com?12234")

Comment: Could you please provide the ampscript code for URL generation and output (the actual a tag)? This would help finding the issue

Comment: I had this issue as well - this happened when there were two '?' characters in url. Can you post your whole url?

Answer (score 1):

According to [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/urlencode.htm), you can choose multiple options on what an how to URL Encode your string. What you are looking for is probably this solution:

```
URLEncode('http://example.com?p=examplé',1,0)
```

This will only encode whatever is provided after *?* - hence returning:
*http://example.com?p%3dexampl%c3%a9*